# How to adjust daily stock prices dataframe for weekend to create a timeseries which can be decomposed in r?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a **daily frequency dataframe** which I am trying to convert as **timeseries** data & then do `decompose()` on it. Daily freq stock data doesn't have weekend data in it so I am not sure how to deal with general formula `ts(frequency = 365)`

Code that I have attempted:

**data**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(quantmod)
library(zoo)
library(xts)

adani_green_df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/adani_daily_data.csv")
```

Getting **day of the year** for `start()` formula input

```
adani_green_df %>% 
  head(n = 1) %>% 
  mutate(day_of_year = lubridate::yday(date)) %>% 
  select(date, day_of_year)

######### output ###########
date       day_of_year
  <date>           <dbl>
1 2018-06-18         169
```

I am not sure if the formula that I have used in below code: `ts(frequency = 365, start = c(2018,169))` is correct or not ?

```
adani_green_df %>% 
  select(date,CLOSE) %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c("date","close")) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("date") %>% 
  as.xts() %>% 
  # print(.,calendar = TRUE) %>% 
  ts(frequency = 365, start = c(2018,169)) %>% 
  decompose() %>% 
  plot()
```

[image]

**Reason of Doubt:** The above plot **doesn't show 2022 data** where as the **max date** in data is `2022-09-19` as checked in below code:

```
# getting data range of Stock prices
adani_green_df %>% 
  select(date) %>% 
  summary()

######### output ##########
      date           
 Min.   :2018-06-18  
 1st Qu.:2019-07-14  
 Median :2020-08-06  
 Mean   :2020-08-04  
 3rd Qu.:2021-08-26  
 Max.   :2022-09-19
```

---

**Update 1:** Attempting code based on Answer 1

```
library(timetk)
plot_stl_diagnostics(adani_green_df, .date_var = date, .value = CLOSE)
```

[image]

```
plot_stl_diagnostics(adani_green_df, .date_var = date, .value = CLOSE,.feature_set = c("season"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want a full cycle to be a year, the key issue, as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73789265/how-to-convert-daily-frequency-dataframe-into-weekly-time-series-in-r/73790418), is how to align the data so that there are the same number of points in each year.  Calculate a table of the number of points in each year, `tab`.  Then find `min_days` which is the minimum number of days per year excluding potentially short years which are the first and last years and then remove any points having a day number greater than `min_days` giving `zz`.  Using that we can generate a regular ts series, `tser`, which is aligned with year and can be used with decompose.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.csv.zoo(u) # u is URL given in Note at end

yr <- as.numeric(format(time(z), "%Y"))
tab <- table(yr)
min_days <- min(tab[seq(2, length(tab)-1)])
zz <- z[ave(yr, yr, FUN = seq_along) <= min_days]
tser <- ts(zz, start = c(yr[1], min_days - tab[[1]] + 1), freq = min_days)
```

### Note

```
u <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/adani_daily_data.csv"
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I try reading with zoo `z <- read.csv.zoo(u, format = '%d-%b-%y')`. Error: `Error in read.zoo(..., read = read) : 
index has 1056 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ......`

Comment: Sorry. I had assumed that the link was the same as in your last post.  It works if we remove the format= argument which I have now  done in the revised answer.

Comment: Yes it works now. And I got the perfect result as well. Thanks again for helping me out on time series questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face here is that the `ts` function creates an internal counter and creates a timeseries starting at 2018, day 169 and then starts counting. Each observation an extra day, not skipping any non-business days. One option is adjusting the frequency to +/- 220 as these are roughly the number of trading days in a year.

**timetk, modeltime**

Personally, I use the timetk, modeltime and tidymodels for dealing with stock prices. timetk can handle decompositions of data without weekends and shows the plots in  plotly. modeltime in combination with tidymodels can handle any forecasting you need.

Example code, plot not included.

```
library(timetk)
plot_stl_diagnostics(adani_green_df, .date_var = Date, .value = close)
#frequency = 5 observations per 1 week
#trend = 66 observations per 3 months
```

**fable, feasts, tsibble**

You can also use fable, the successor from forecast.

What you can do is create an index (or use a variable as an index). In the example below I create a variable idx to use as the index. Keep any groupings you need in mind when creating an index.

Forecasting is done based on this index. So forecast(model, h = 12) will forecast 12 index values into the future. You then need to translate that back into your date column. Example code below, plot not included.

```
library(fable)
library(feasts)
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)

fc <- adani_green_df %>% 
  mutate(idx = row_number()) %>% 
  tsibble(index = idx)

dcmp <- fc %>%
  model(stl = STL(close))

components(dcmp) %>% autoplot()
```

Of course you could also use prophet. But the above two options include ways of using prophet in them without using prophet directly. This saves in renaming column names and other things that are being done to make everything work.

Comment: Thanks @phiver, I have tried your code `plot_stl_diagnostics()` but it is giving me a strange `seasonality` plot. And I was getting an error when I tried `components(dcmp) %>% autoplot()`. I have updated the code & plot in the post as `Update 1:` section

Answer (score 0):

I have also made an attempt to solve this by **filling the missing weekend dates** & then carry forward the non na Close price to overwrite the na's & then decompose & plot it.

```
library(padr)

adani_green_df_filled <- adani_green_df %>% 
  select(date,CLOSE) %>% 
  padr::pad(.) %>%                  # fill missing dates
  mutate(CLOSE = na.locf(CLOSE))    # carry forward non na values to replace na values

adani_green_df_filled
```

```
adani_green_df_filled %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c("date","close")) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("date") %>% 
  as.xts() %>% 
  ts(frequency = 365, start = c(2018,169)) %>% 
  decompose() %>% 
  plot()
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt this approach can work.  Consider that 2/7 which is nearly 30% of the data would be imputed which seems far too high to get reliable results.

Comment: Yes even I had this doubt in my mind but also the price doesn't change on weekend so I am also in a state of may be may be not to do this .